# Numpy polyfit find least divergent

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy polyfit to create a number of plots which show a line of best fit. This works fine.. But I am wondering... Is it possible to assertain WHICH one of my plots has got the "straightest" line
Not sure what the correct term is...
I guess from the data points given, which set of data is least divergent?
ie:
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
this would be giving me a perfect fit... how can I find which is the most perfect fit?

Answer (score 1):

Fitting Algorithms like Regression has a metric showing it's accuracy named RMSE (root mean square error) which shows how much does curve deviates from points. It is explained [here](https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/regression-analysis/rmse-root-mean-square-error/) well.
[image: RMSE formulation]